# Group 2d array data by one column and sum other columns in each group (separately)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I need to group the data in my indexed array of indexed arrays by the first column values (id column).  Within each group, I need to find the sum of the second column and find the sum of the third column.

Sample input:

```
[
    [111, 5, 3],
    [111, 3, 7],
    [111, 2, 1],
    [222, 5, 3],
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
    111 => [10, 11]
    222 => [5, 3]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to do this manually using a loop. Something like this should work:

```
$result = array();

foreach( $input as $row) {
    $id = array_shift( $row);

    foreach( $row as $key => $value) {

        $result[ $id ][ $key ] = 
            ( isset( $result[ $id ][ $key ]) ? 
                  $result[ $id ][ $key ] + $value : 
                  $value
            );
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) {
  [111]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
    [1]=>
    int(11)
  }
  [222]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4eBIHI)

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple

```
foreach ($arrays as $array) {

    $final[$array[0]] = array(
        @$final[$array[0]][0] + $array[1],
        @$final[$array[0]][1] + $array[2]
    );
}
```

http://codepad.org/lCCXHjKR

Answer (score 0):

## Code

```
// This is your input.
$Input[] = array(
  0=>111, //id
  1=>5,   //value to ad
  2=>3   //value to ad
);
$Input[] = array(
  0=>111,
  1=>3,
  2=>7   
);
$Input[] = array(
  0=>111,
  1=>2,
  2=>1   
);
$Input[] = array(
  0=>222,
  1=>5,
  2=>3   
);

// This is your output.
$Output = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($Input); $i++)
{
    $id = $Input[$i][0];

    // If key already exists...
    if(array_key_exists($id, $Output))
    {
        // Sum it.
        $Output[$id][0] += $Input[$i][1];
        $Output[$id][1] += $Input[$i][2];
    }
    // If not...
    else
    {
        // Initialize it.
        $Output[$id][0] = $Input[$i][1];
        $Output[$id][1] = $Input[$i][2];
    }
}

// This is your output dumped.
print_r($Output);
```

## Output

```
Array
(
    [111] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 11
        )

    [222] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

## Additional Note

The key is to use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to check if an index already exists in an array.

Answer (score 0):

A concise, modern approach using a language construct is to iterate the inout array with `foreach()` and leverage the null coalescing operator when adding related data points.  This prevents any warnings cause by trying to add a value to an undeclared variable.  Using the `@` symbol to suppress errors should be avoided because it represents a willingness to ignore meaningful feedback from the server (and generally developers believe that unnecessary error suppression gives code a bad smell).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/o6v6h))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[$row[0]][0] = ($result[$row[0]][0] ?? 0) + $row[1];
    $result[$row[0]][1] = ($result[$row[0]][1] ?? 0) + $row[2];
}
var_export($result);
```

---

`array_reduce()` offers the same result as a functional alternative which also prevents declaring a variable in the global scope.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GAenR))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function($result, $row) {
            $result[$row[0]][0] = ($result[$row[0]][0] ?? 0) + $row[1];
            $result[$row[0]][1] = ($result[$row[0]][1] ?? 0) + $row[2];
            return $result;
        }
    )
);
```