# How can I sum values of an array with the same key sorted by category?

Tags: php, arrays, sum, key

`category`:

```
array:3 [▼
  "78f895684c" => "blue"
  "f71db561ba" => "green"
  "3e231651de" => "blue"
]
```

`numbersGroup:`

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "uuid" => "78f895684c"
    "price" => "10"
    "discount" => "0"
    "total" => "10.00"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "uuid" => "f71db561ba"
    "price" => "2"
    "discount" => "0"
    "total" => "2.00"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "uuid" => "3e231651de"
    "price" => "50"
    "discount" => "10"
    "total" => "40.00"
  ]
]
```

I try to create an array that sorts my items into categories, but also sums all items in a category together. This is what I have:

```
  foreach ($numbersGroup as $group) {
      $cat = $category[$group['uuid']];
      unset($group['uuid']);
      $numbersArray[$cat][] = $group;
    }
```

With the result:

```
array:2 [▼
  "blue" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "price" => "10"
      "discount" => "0"
      "total" => "10.00"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "price" => "50"
      "discount" => "10"
      "total" => "40.00"
    ]
  ]
  "green" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "price" => "2"
      "discount" => "0"
      "total" => "2.00"
    ]
  ]
]
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
 array:2 [▼
      "blue" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
          "price" => "60"
          "discount" => "10"
          "total" => "50.00"
        ]
      ]
      "green" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
          "price" => "2"
          "discount" => "0"
          "total" => "2.00"
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

This is my approach:

```
foreach ($numbersGroup as $group) {
  $cat = $category[$group['uuid']];
  unset($group['uuid']);
  foreach ($group as $key => $value) {
    $sum += $value;
  }
  $numbersArray[$cat][] = $sum;
}
```

But I get the error:

> Unsupported operand types

Comment: Check if `$numbersArray[$cat]` is already set - if so, don’t add a new array element, but add the individual values to the existing array keys.

Comment: @04FS  when I `dump($numbersArray[$cat]);` then I get the error `Undefined variable: numbersArray`

Comment: `dump` is a debug function - checking whether a variable or array key is set, is `isset`’s job.

Comment: Related: [Group 2d array data by one column and sum other columns in each group (separately)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11006797/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `$numbersArray[$cat]` is already set - if so, don’t add a new array element, but add the individual values to the existing array keys.

```
foreach ($numbersGroup as $group) {
  $cat = $category[$group['uuid']];
  unset($group['uuid']);
  if(isset($numbersArray[$cat])) {
    $numbersArray[$cat]['price'] += $group['price'];
    $numbersArray[$cat]['discount'] += $group['discount'];
    $numbersArray[$cat]['total'] += $group['total'];
  }
  else {
    $numbersArray[$cat] = $group; // no [] here, because we want only a single element
  }
}
```

Or, without an explicit if, using the `??` operator instead:

```
foreach ($numbersGroup as $group) {
      $cat = $category[$group['uuid']];
      $numbersArray[$cat]['price'] = ($numbersArray[$cat]['price'] ?? 0) + $group['price'];
      $numbersArray[$cat]['discount'] = ($numbersArray[$cat]['discount'] ?? 0) + $group['discount'];
      $numbersArray[$cat]['total'] = ($numbersArray[$cat]['total'] ?? 0) + $group['total'];
}
```

--
Edit:

> I unfortunately I cannot write into my code "price", "discount" etc, because these values are always different, this cannot be hardcoded

Then loop over the keys you get from group, as you tried to with your initial code already:

```
foreach ($numbersGroup as $group) {
  $cat = $category[$group['uuid']];
  unset($group['uuid']);
  foreach($group as $key => $value) {
    $numbersArray[$cat][$key] = ($numbersArray[$cat][$key] ?? 0) + $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I unfortunately I cannot write into my code "price", "discount" etc, because these values are always different, this cannot be hardcoded

Comment: @peace_love see edit, loop over the keys you get in the group then, as you already tried to do with your initial attempt.

Comment: Ah, I just see, that your solution is not creating a subkey in the array, like in Ajith answer this works. I tested your answer with `$numbersArray[$cat][0][$key]` but then the total amount is wrong

Comment: Because actually I need the key not to be 0, instead I need it to be a word like `$numbersArray[$cat]['sum'][$key]`

Comment: Did you modify it accordingly in _both_ places? `$numbersArray[$cat]['sum'][$key] = ($numbersArray[$cat]['sum'][$key] ?? 0) + $value;`

Comment: (And the next time you ask something here, all these “additional” requirements should be contained in your question right from the start …)

Comment: Ah no, this was what I forgot

Comment: (But in my question you see, that it is asked for the subkey solution right from the beginning)

Comment: Yeah, kinda - you had numeric keys in there. I meant more in combination with the keys having to be dynamic … Doesn’t matter, as long as problem solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code

```
foreach ($numbersGroup as $group) {
  $cat = $category[$group['uuid']];
  if(!isset( $numbersArray[$cat][0]) )
    $numbersArray[$cat][] = $group;
  else{
     // If index is known, you can use below code
    /*$numbersArray[$cat][0]["price"]+=  $group['price'];
    $numbersArray[$cat][0]["discount"]+=  $group['discount'];
    $numbersArray[$cat][0]["total"]+=  $group['total'];*/


    // If index is not known
    foreach($group as $key => $value){
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $numbersArray[$cat][0][$key]+=  $group[$key];
        }
    }


  }     
}
```

Now I have added the case if array index is not known. We need a numeric checking before adding the values.
I hope this helps you :)

Comment: I unfortunately need a not hardcoded solution, because it is not alwas price, sometimes there are other values, or more values